# What is { } used for in Microsoft Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I came across this function in one of my worksheets and wanted to know what the curly braces are used for.

Here is an example.

```
{=array(sheet1!a1,sheet2!a3,sheet2!a5,sheet2!a6)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are used in `Array Formulas`.

```
Excel surrounds the formula with braces ({ }) and places an 
instance of the formula in each cell of the selected range.
```

Source - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010342564.aspx

Answer (score 3):

That's an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx).
It applies to a range of cells.

Comment: what about the {} brackets? thats what I want to know?

Comment: The {} brackets surround array formulas. That's what he's saying.